# Почему при сортировке удаляются формулы?

Tags: google-spreadsheet, google-apps-script

Код в GAS сортирует данные в гугл таблице в диапазоне A2:F999

В столбцах ABCD стоят формулы
В столбцах EF стоит текст в виде числа, вроде такого:
-3,45
4
-6,78
5,2
94

Причем сортирует он правильно всё, но не могу побороть что при сортировке строк в столбцах ABCD, он устанавливает вместо формул их значение (результат формулы)

**Основное ядро сортировки вот в этой функции sortSheetByColumn() где и кроется проблема:**

```js
function sortSheetByColumn(columnIndex, shouldConvertToPercent) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  clearZeroPercentages(); // Очистка нулевых процентов перед сортировкой
  removePercentageSign(); // Удаление символа процента
  
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var range = sheet.getRange('A2:F' + lastRow);
  var data = range.getValues();

  // Сопоставляем значения указанного столбца с индексами строк
  var indexedData = data.map(function(row, index) {
    var value = row[columnIndex - 1]; // Используем columnIndex для динамического определения столбца
    var number = value ? parseFloat(value.toString().replace(',', '.')) : null;
    return { index: index, value: number };
  });

  // Сортировка данных с учетом пустых значений
  indexedData.sort(function(a, b) {
    if (a.value === null) return 1; // Пустые значения в конец
    if (b.value === null) return -1; // Пустые значения в начало
    return b.value - a.value; // Сортировка по убыванию
  });

  // Создаем новый массив данных в соответствии с отсортированными индексами
  var sortedData = indexedData.map(function(item) {
    return data[item.index];
  });

  // Записываем отсортированные данные обратно в диапазон
  range.setValues(sortedData);
```

**Весь код:**

```js
// сортирует отлично в столбцах E и F но единственная проблемма, то что он удаляет формулы в ячейках в столбцах A B C D , а так всё отлично. Отлично сортирует отрицательные и положительные числа
function sortSheetByColumnE() {
  sortSheetByColumn(5, false); // Сортировка по столбцу E без изменения формата
  addPercentageToCells(); // Вызов функции для добавления символа процента в конец каждой ячейки диапазона E2:F999
}

function sortSheetByColumnF() {
  sortSheetByColumn(6, true); // Сортировка по столбцу F с изменением формата на проценты
  addPercentageToCells(); // Вызов функции для добавления символа процента в конец каждой ячейки диапазона E2:F999
}


// добавляем символ процента в конец каждой ячейки диапазона E2:F999
function addPercentageToCells() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange('E2:F999'); // Выбираем диапазон E2:F999
  var values = range.getValues(); // Получаем значения в диапазоне
  // Перебираем все строки и столбцы в диапазоне
  for (var row = 0; row < values.length; row++) {
    for (var col = 0; col < values[row].length; col++) {
      if (values[row][col] !== '') { // Проверяем, не пустая ли ячейка
        values[row][col] += '%'; // Добавляем символ процента
      }
    }
  }
  range.setValues(values); // Обновляем ячейки новыми значениями
}

 // очищаем все ячейки где стоит 0% в диапазоне E2:E 999
function clearZeroPercentages() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var rangeE = sheet.getRange("E2:E" + lastRow);
  var rangeF = sheet.getRange("F2:F" + lastRow);
  var valuesE = rangeE.getValues();
  var valuesF = rangeF.getValues();
  // Очищаем ячейки, содержащие 0% в столбцах E и F
  valuesE.forEach(function(row, i) {
    if (row[0] === '0%') row[0] = '';
  });
  valuesF.forEach(function(row, i) {
    if (row[0] === '0%') row[0] = '';
  });
  // Устанавливаем обновленные значения обратно в лист
  rangeE.setValues(valuesE);
  rangeF.setValues(valuesF);
}

// удаляем из диапазона E2:E999 из всех ячеек символа процента
function removePercentageSign() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange("E2:F999");
  var data = range.getValues();
  // Удаляем символ процента из всех ячейк
  var newData = data.map(function(row) {
    return row.map(function(cell) {
      if (typeof cell === 'string' && cell.endsWith('%')) {
        return cell.slice(0, -1);
      }
      return cell;
    });
  });

  // Устанавливаем обновленные данные обратно в диапазон
  range.setValues(newData);
}


 // функция сортировки внутри которой мы сначала чистим ячейки в диапазоне E2:E999 где стоит ноль,
 // потом удаляем из E2:E999 в ячейках символы процентов
function sortSheetByColumn(columnIndex, shouldConvertToPercent) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  clearZeroPercentages(); // Очистка нулевых процентов перед сортировкой
  removePercentageSign(); // Удаление символа процента
  
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var range = sheet.getRange('A2:F' + lastRow);
  var data = range.getValues();

  // Сопоставляем значения указанного столбца с индексами строк
  var indexedData = data.map(function(row, index) {
    var value = row[columnIndex - 1]; // Используем columnIndex для динамического определения столбца
    var number = value ? parseFloat(value.toString().replace(',', '.')) : null;
    return { index: index, value: number };
  });

  // Сортировка данных с учетом пустых значений
  indexedData.sort(function(a, b) {
    if (a.value === null) return 1; // Пустые значения в конец
    if (b.value === null) return -1; // Пустые значения в начало
    return b.value - a.value; // Сортировка по убыванию
  });

  // Создаем новый массив данных в соответствии с отсортированными индексами
  var sortedData = indexedData.map(function(item) {
    return data[item.index];
  });

  // Записываем отсортированные данные обратно в диапазон
  range.setValues(sortedData);

}
```

Comment: Зачем слать все эти портянки? Может быть было бы проще сделать пример без лишних данных и шелухи и прислать ссылку на Таблицу? Авось, пока делали бы, само бы решилось.

Answer (score 0):

сам сделал . вот так заработало как я хотел:

```js
function sortSheetByColumnE() {
  sortSheetByColumn(5, false); // Сортировка по столбцу E без изменения формата
  addPercentageToCells(); // Вызов функции для добавления символа процента в конец каждой ячейки диапазона E2:F999
  fillEmptyWithZeroPercentage()
}

function sortSheetByColumnF() {
  sortSheetByColumn(6, true); // Сортировка по столбцу F с изменением формата на проценты
  addPercentageToCells(); // Вызов функции для добавления символа процента в конец каждой ячейки диапазона E2:F999
  fillEmptyWithZeroPercentage()
}





// добавляем символ процента в конец каждой ячейки диапазона E2:F999
function addPercentageToCells() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange('E2:F999'); // Выбираем диапазон E2:F999
  var values = range.getValues(); // Получаем значения в диапазоне
  // Перебираем все строки и столбцы в диапазоне
  for (var row = 0; row < values.length; row++) {
    for (var col = 0; col < values[row].length; col++) {
      if (values[row][col] !== '') { // Проверяем, не пустая ли ячейка
        values[row][col] += '%'; // Добавляем символ процента
      }
    }
  }
  range.setValues(values); // Обновляем ячейки новыми значениями
}

 // очищаем все ячейки где стоит 0% в диапазоне E2:E 999
function clearZeroPercentages() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var rangeE = sheet.getRange("E2:E" + lastRow);
  var rangeF = sheet.getRange("F2:F" + lastRow);
  var valuesE = rangeE.getValues();
  var valuesF = rangeF.getValues();
  // Очищаем ячейки, содержащие 0% в столбцах E и F
  valuesE.forEach(function(row, i) {
    if (row[0] === '0%') row[0] = '';
  });
  valuesF.forEach(function(row, i) {
    if (row[0] === '0%') row[0] = '';
  });
  // Устанавливаем обновленные значения обратно в лист
  rangeE.setValues(valuesE);
  rangeF.setValues(valuesF);
}

// удаляем из диапазона E2:E999 из всех ячеек символа процента
function removePercentageSign() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange("E2:F999");
  var data = range.getValues();
  // Удаляем символ процента из всех ячейк
  var newData = data.map(function(row) {
    return row.map(function(cell) {
      if (typeof cell === 'string' && cell.endsWith('%')) {
        return cell.slice(0, -1);
      }
      return cell;
    });
  });

  // Устанавливаем обновленные данные обратно в диапазон
  range.setValues(newData);
}

 // во все ячейки где пустота , ставим 0% в диапазоне E2:F999
function fillEmptyWithZeroPercentage() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var lastRow = sheet.getRange("A" + sheet.getLastRow()).getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.UP).getRow();
  var rangeE = sheet.getRange("E2:E" + lastRow);
  var rangeF = sheet.getRange("F2:F" + lastRow);
  var valuesE = rangeE.getValues();
  var valuesF = rangeF.getValues();

  // Заполняем пустые ячейки текстом "0%" в столбцах E и F
  valuesE.forEach(function(row, i) {
    if (!row[0]) row[0] = '0%'; // Если ячейка пуста, заполняем её "0%"
  });
  valuesF.forEach(function(row, i) {
    if (!row[0]) row[0] = '0%'; // Если ячейка пуста, заполняем её "0%"
  });

  // Устанавливаем обновленные значения обратно в лист
  rangeE.setValues(valuesE);
  rangeF.setValues(valuesF);
}





 // функция сортировки внутри которой мы сначала чистим ячейки в диапазоне E2:F999 где стоит ноль,
 // потом удаляем из E2:F999 в ячейках символы процентов
function sortSheetByColumn(columnIndex, shouldConvertToPercent) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  
  clearZeroPercentages(); // Очистка нулевых процентов перед сортировкой
  removePercentageSign(); // Удаление символа процента

  // Вызываем кастомную функцию сортировки
  customSort(sheet, columnIndex);


}


function customSort(sheet, columnIndex) {
  // Получаем данные и формулы
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var range = sheet.getRange('A2:F' + lastRow);
  var data = range.getValues();
  var formulas = range.getFormulas();

  // Привязываем значения и формулы к их индексам
  var combinedData = data.map(function(row, index) {
    return {
      value: row[columnIndex - 1],
      formulas: formulas[index],
      index: index,
      row: row
    };
  });

  // Сортировка
  combinedData.sort(compare);

  // Разделяем отсортированные значения и формулы
  var sortedValues = combinedData.map(function(item) { return item.row; });
  var sortedFormulas = combinedData.map(function(item) { return item.formulas; });

  // Записываем отсортированные данные
  range.setValues(sortedValues);

  // Обновляем формулы
  sortedFormulas.forEach(function(rowFormulas, rowIndex) {
    rowFormulas.forEach(function(formula, colIndex) {
      if (formula) { // Обновляем только ячейки с формулами
        sheet.getRange(rowIndex + 2, colIndex + 1).setFormula(formula);
      }
    });
  });
}


function compare(a, b) {
  var valA = a.value === '' || a.value === '0%' ? 0 : parseFloat(a.value.replace(',', '.'));
  var valB = b.value === '' || b.value === '0%' ? 0 : parseFloat(b.value.replace(',', '.'));

  // Положительные числа идут перед нулями и отрицательными числами, сортируются по убыванию
  if (valA > 0 && valB <= 0) return -1;
  if (valB > 0 && valA <= 0) return 1;
  if (valA > 0 && valB > 0) return valB - valA;

  // Нули идут после положительных и отрицательных чисел
  if (valA === 0 && valB !== 0) return 1;
  if (valB === 0 && valA !== 0) return -1;

  // Среди отрицательных чисел меньшее по абсолютной величине число идет перед большим
  if (valA < 0 && valB < 0) return Math.abs(valA) - Math.abs(valB);

  return 0; // Если все проверки пройдены и значения равны, порядок не меняется
}
```